# If I am submitting two different provisionals for two different claims on the same invention can some sections be the same or similar?

Tags: patent-applications, provisional-application, provisional

Hi if I am submitting two provisional patent applications for two different claims but for the same invention can sections such as background, summary, drawings, detailed description, terminology, and remarks be similar or even the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And the direct answer to your question is yes, if you have some reason to file two provisionals. Lets say you file one and then decide you have another aspect of the system that you think is patentable. Feel free to copy whatever is relevant from the first one you filed.

And, there is no such thing as a provisional *patent*, only a provisional patent *application*.

Answer (score 1):

Hi I called the inventor's assistance center regarding my question above, and they suggested that I file one provisional and then when filing the non-provisional do two separate claims.

Comment: It is perfectly fine to answer your own question and even accept it. That said if I were you I’d remove the informal language and add whatever additional information you might have received. The idea is to make the answer as useful as possible to future readers.